# ember cli could not find watchman on ubuntu, there is only solution for mac not for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ember.js, ember-cli, watchman

ember -v

version: 2.3.0

Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.

Visit http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.

node: 5.0.0

os: linux x64

---

http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman there is only solution for mac not for ubuntu

Comment: Does this help: http://codeyarns.com/2015/02/10/how-to-install-and-use-watchman/

Answer (score 1):

Although it is true that there is no harm in ignoring the error message on your Linux system, be aware that installing watchman for your ember project gives you additional freedom in configuring the file watching process, e.g. being able to [define which directories are ignored when watching your project for changes](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/config.html#ignore_dirs).

Full installation instructions for watchman on other operating systems than OSX can be found in the [official watchman documentation](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#build-install).

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the log message, watchman was added specifically for osx as node watcher was causing [some problems](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2226)